# What Licence does JDSOFT.APNS fall under?

Tags: c#, asp.net, apple-push-notifications

I would want to use Apple's notification service and i found that [JDSOFT APNS](https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp) is a widely used one. Please suggest if there is any better library than this.

Question: I could not find any License information on the project and if there is one can i use it for commercial purpose?

Preferred language:C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found.... it is licensed with Apache 2.0 [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/) 
And it can be used commercially.